# DateFormatter gives wrong date

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

I am using the date picker to change the date in my app.

This functions fine so far, but now I try to display the date that is currently chosen in the date picker with `DateFormatter`. This is the code that is not working for me:

```
let strDate = "02. November 2020"
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateformat = "dd. MMMM yyyy"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let date = formatter.date(from: strDate)
// output here is 2020-11-01 23:00:00 UTC
let strTemp = formatter.string(from: date)
// output here is 02. November 2020
```

As you can see the output string from the 'wrong' date is still correct which is why I have not noticed it until now.
The problem now is, that the `DatePicker` is displaying the 01. November 2020 and not the 02. November 2020.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I guess it's because of some issues with your timezone and the difference between utc and cest (for germany).

Comment: you can set the timezone yourself, like `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")` this will give you "2020-11-02 00:00:00 +0000"

Comment: _"the date that is currently choosen"_, why is this a String instance and not a Date instance?

Comment: The date is correct. `2020-11-01 23:00:00 UTC` and `2020-11-02 00:00:00 +0100` are the same point in time. Consider that `print` displays dates always in UTC+0000